# How to create contact in Azure AD

Tags: azure, exchange-server, contacts

I need to create contacts programmatically so that it would appear in the Global Address List of Exchange Online user. It is my understanding that those contacts are Azure AD contacts, but Graph REST API only supports getting contacts: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151612.aspx.

I already [asked](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9462782d-3062-4b70-a387-4629d91f607c/creating-contacts?forum=WindowsAzureAD) on Azure AD forum and was told there's no functionality to add/update contacts.

Is there any other way to create a contact so that it would appear in the Global Address List?

Comment: A quick test shows me that Contacts created in Office 365 are not the same as Users in an Azure Directory (users see the contact via exchange, but it is not listed in the Azure Directory).  You may be confusing the two?

Comment: Hi Brendan, I might be. I know that If I create contacts using EWS, they are created as personal contacts attached to the authenticated account, and not as global contacts. You're right, we can't see the contacts in Azure AD, but that doesn't mean they are not there. After all, in an on-prem environment, contacts are AD objects, not an Exchange ones. And if there's a way to [get Azure AD contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151612.aspx), there must be a way to save them, no?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, personal contacts (stored in a user's mailbox) are completely separate from Global Address Contacts (stored in the Active Directory in on-premise Exchange setups, Azure AD in Office 365). Since Graph API doesn't support creating them, to actually create GAL contacts you would have to use PowerShell. The [New-MailContact cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124519(v=exchg.150).aspx) should do the trick.